# gesture recognizer в GMSmapView

Tags: swift, google-maps-api, gestures

Привет всем, столкнулся в проблемой в использовании жестов в GMSmapView(google maps). Когда я делаю свайп для вызова бокового меню, то карта тоже продолжает движение в сторону жеста, я пробовал делать `mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)` во время `viewWillAppear`(боковое меню), но он отключает жесты для карты только тогда, когда я отпущу палец. Вопрос, как отключить жесты для карты во время того когда я открываю боковое меню.

Карта на картинке(справа) продолжает движение во время открывания меню

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ну можно такой вариант сделать вешаем на вью свайп в право + добавим область для начала отображения бокового меню

```
var rightMenuRect : CGRect?

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     self.rightMenuRec = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: self.view1.frame.size.height)

     var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
     swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
     self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
}

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        let location = swipeGesture.location(ofTouch touchIndex: 0, in view: self.view)

        if (rightMenuRect?.contains(location))! && swipeGesture.state == .began {
             mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)
             // дальше отображаем меню
        }

        if swipeGesture.state == .ended {
            mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Отличная идея, но не срабатывает. Делает тоже самое что и мой код, отключает тач после того как меню открылось, а процессе открытия карта все равно прокручивается